# Remove ' from header in python

Tags: python, post, request, request-headers

I'm trying to work with an API that requires Authorization headers, but it doesn't interpret ' at my api key.
So if i send

```py
headers = {"Authorization": "api_key"}
res=request.post("https://endpoint.com/Login/authenticate", headers=headers)
```

the page throws a 500 because python sends the headers like

```
'Authorization': 'api_key'
```

While in Curl i don't have this error because it sends

```
Authorization: api_key
```

Is there a way to make python not add the ' at the headers?

I've tried to send the headers as only one string but python doesn't accept it.

Example:

```py
headers = "Authorization: api_key"
res=request.post("https://endpoint.com/Login/authenticate", headers=headers)
```

Comment: I made a dummy server that just prints what it receives.  It does not receive the key with quotes using your post code.  You'll have to provide a [mcve].